# CarrierWave file size validator keeps image in /tmp/ directory when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, carrierwave

I am following this [tutorial for file size validation with Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size) and it's working as it should for the most part.

In my model...

```
validates :image, :file_size => { :maximum => 2.megabytes.to_i }
```

If I go to upload a 5MB image I get the error **Image is too big (should be at most 2 MB)**. Great! Problem is the 5MB file sticks around in `/uploads/tmp/`. Obviously this could become extremely resource intensive and I don't want the file to save whatsoever if it was too large.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am using Heroku and think it might have something to do with caching and form redisplays. See [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku). I guess in other words what I'm trying to do is disable form redisplays for the image? Because the image does show (unprocessed and sourced from the `/uploads/tmp/` dir). Though if I reload the page (not resubmitting the form) the image disappears from the form, but the file still remains in the `/tmp` dir. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete file by `#remove!` when validation failed.

```
# lib/file_size_validator.rb
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  ...
  CHECKS.each do |key, validity_check|
     ...
    record.errors.add(attribute, MESSAGES[key], errors_options)
    if options[:remove_if_invalid]
      # Remove cached file
      value.remove!
    end
  end
end

# in model source
validates :image, :file_size => { :maximum => 2.megabytes.to_i, :remove_if_invalid => true }
```

If you dislike destructive operation during validation, you may set a flag and remove file later.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and used the solution provided by @labocho, but after that, carrierwave's redisplay is not working any more. So, I created a function in my controller to check and delete old image cache folder and use it as a before_filter function for form processing action. There is no problem so far. My code is like this:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :remove_old_cache, only: [:create]

  # Handle image creation
  def create
    ...
  end

  # Delete tmp image directory if validation fails (for carrier wave)  
  def remove_old_cache
    image = params[:image]
    if image[:image] && !image[:image_cache].empty?
      cache_name = image[:image_cache]
      # get the cache directory
      cache_dir = cache_name.split('/')[0]
      FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join("#{Rails.root}", "/public/uploads/tmp/", cache_dir))
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: how would this work if using nested_attributes, and had many images, so say i had this animal_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image_cache"=>"",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000053f6718 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140924-11401-1euat67>,
 @original_filename="cat.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"animal[animal_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"cat.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Advert"}

Comment: with some adjustments ive got it working, going to try and iterate through an array of hashes now